# Google app script regex syntax

Tags: javascript, regex

What the hell is wrong with this?? For the life in me I can't figure it out.

```
link = item.getChild("link", atom).getAttribute("href").getValue().replaceText("(https:\/\/www\.google\.com\/url\?rct=j&sa=t&url=|&ct=ga.*)","");
```

I've tried all sorts of permutations. 'item' is a child in an xml from an atom file:

```
item = items[i];
```

This, for instance, works:

```
link = item.getChild("link", atom).getAttribute("href").getValue().replace("https://www.google.com/url?rct=j&sa=t&url=","");
```

The goal here, as it might've become apparent, is to get rid of Google's crapware around the results it yields in an alerts feed. I also tried:

```
link = item.getChild("link", atom).getAttribute("href").getValue().replace("https://www.google.com/url?rct=j&sa=t&url=","").replaceText("&ct=ga.*","");
```

No avail. And also:

```
link = item.getChild("link", atom).getAttribute("href").getValue().replace("https://www.google.com/url?rct=j&sa=t&url=","");
link = link.replaceText("&ct=ga.*","");
```

Nope, not that either. What gives? To make matters worse, some caching is going on and doesn't really help testing the script. That, btw, is [here](https://script.google.com/d/1TPa4CnjALJud-0-DIDssDODTK_zYeQrj2q0CSxKhgGVfKaaI2CCSid1X/edit?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 1):

Apps Script is JavaScript which deals with Regular Expressions in a specific way. Likewise the `String.replace()` function also works in two particular ways — string replacement and regex match replacement. You are trying to use regex in the string replacement manner.

Cf. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

You need to use the `.replace(pattern, replacement)` version. pattern here is a regex object and not a string. Define the pattern object right there in the method or as a separate declaration (`new RegExp()`)

Cf. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Tldr; To define a regex object inline use `/` to enclose it and not `"`.

So:

`/(https:\/\/www\.google\.com\/url\?rct=j&sa=turl=|&ct=ga.*)/` which I don't think will work for you in any case.

Try matching and not removing what you don't what you want to extract and not removing what you don't.

```
link = (function (link) {
  var match = link.match(/#.*[?&]url=([^&]+)(&|$)/);
  return(match ? match[1] : "");
}(item.getChild("link", atom).getAttribute("href").getValue());
```